# Large doubles, format to NSString with Points

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, string-formatting

I have a few large double like **11223322**. Is there a way when I convert the `double` in a `NSString` that I will have the format like this: **11.223.322** ?

Comment: u need to format your string : use regex or substring feature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with following code;

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[numberFormatter setGroupingSeparator:@"."]; // Here you can change Separator as you want 
NSString *formattedNumberString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:@11223322];
NSLog(@"formattedNumberString: %@", formattedNumberString);
```

Comment: @christzone: Note that grouping separator is different in different locales. For example, while it's `.` in Germany (most of Europe?), it's `,` in the US. Instead of setting the grouping separator to fixed value, try using `[numberFormatter setUsesGroupingSeparator:YES];` or get the grouping separator from the current locale.